# Getting previous value in array after selecting next file through input file

Tags: reactjs, input, file-upload

Because of this problem, I get the first value undefined in the array. I am unable to obtain the current file value in the state.
**HandleImage function with useState**

```
const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState([]);
const handleImage = (e) => {
    setImageFile([...imageFile,e.target.files[0]]);
};
```

**Input file component**

```
<input
     type="file"
     className="opacity-0"
     id="image"
     onClick={e => handleImage(e)}
/>
```

[image: State value after selecting 3 values]

State value after selecting 3 values, I got only two values. When I select the first file I got undefined and when I select the 2nd file then I got the value of the 1st file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const handleImage = e => {
  setImages(state => ([...state, e.target.files[0]]));
}
```

Comment: It's not working